# Bootstrap - Navbar is Expanding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a **Bootstrap Navbar** that has *lot of tabs*. The Bootstrap **Nav Bar looks** [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RePb.png)
Is there any way to prevent it.

**The HTML Code:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CDNs/bootstrap.css">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">v1.0</a>
 </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li style="float:right"><a href="#">Upload</a></li>
       <li style="float:right"><a href="#">Events of &copy;</a></li>
       <li style="float:right"><a href="#">Tracker</a></li>
       <li style="float:right"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Return</a></li>
       <li style="float:right"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></span> My< /a></li> 
       <li style="float:right"><a href="signout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> SignOut</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><?php
          echo "Logged in as " . $_SESSION["username"] . "<br>";
          ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

****I have masked few tab names and edited the tab names in the code due to security issues****

Thanks,

Comment: how do u want it to look like??

Comment: Like how the default will look

Comment: Remove the float from all of them, then set them to have `display: inline-block;`, then add a `display: inline-block;` to the `<ul>` as well, and float it right. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ahm7777/zwn82bre/

Comment: Still not working. From 3 columns it came to 2

Comment: is this what you are looking for ? [Codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/ALxzWY)

Comment: No! this is what i was looking for. It did not work.

Comment: This is how any default bootstrap navbar is. You need to tell us what you are expecting. atleast an example link. - Try this https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Comment: Yes, that is what i am expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you need is to have them all in one line, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Ahm7777/zwn82bre/13/) fiddle should work.

These were the only properties needed:

```
.nav.navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is the image:

[image]

You can see all tabs are in order (the signOut tab looks like that because it has an anchor tag on top of it).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is a version of bootstrap got to do with the code. Still not working.

Comment: use the above css and js code because bootstrap min.css and bootstrap.min.js are necessary to execute the bootstrap functionality

Comment: Then it requires debugging...sometimes it happen when jquery or js conflict . You do one thing put bootstrap min.css in header and bootstrap .min.js in footer ..might it may work

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes in your markup

1) There is an extra space on your closing `< /a>` tag in your "My" option

```
<li style="float:right"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></span> My< /a></li>
```

Remove this.

2) Next remove all your inline style (`float:right;`). If you want to shift all towards right then just add the class `navbar-right` to your `<ul>` like this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/ALxzWY)

Comment: did u check the codepen .. does the codepen show what you are expecting ?